# How can I rerun a program with different parameters in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a program that simulates a cellular network depending on a certain number of parameters (antenna profiles and so on) and it takes so time to run as I plot many figures.

Do you guys know how I could automatically rerun the program at the end of the script but with the parameters changing automatically to values I would have chosen before ?

Thanks so much for any kind of help ! :)

Comment: This is very unclear... You should add some code and explain exactly what you want to achieve, and preferably show what you have tried. Check out [ask], [mcve], and [help/on-topic].

Comment: It sounds like your inputs are hard-coded inside your script... What you should do is turn your "main" script into a function and have the parameters you want changed be inputs. Then write a script which calls your `main` with different parameters, e.g. `main(parmA1, paramB1); main(paramA2,paramB2);`. Each consecutive call will only be executed when the previous one finishes. If the parameters of the following run depend on the results of the previous one, make the latter outputs and process them as needed. [Doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did work on my code which is great.
Sorry I have not been more precised I am a first-timer on the website, I will do better next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but you could try this (assuming i understood te question)

```
parameters(NumberOfReruns);  % fill this with the parameters you want to 
                             % use on each run of the program
for i = 1:NumberOfReruns
    program(parameters(i));
end
```